# Resetting a Kafka Stream Application

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

trying to understand how to use the reset tool for kafka stream application. However i am confused by the explanation.

It is said that there are 2 stage to it, local rest (cleanup), followed by the global reset which is using the reset-tool.

The following example is provided in confluent:

```
https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/app-reset-tool.html#step-2-reset-the-local-environments-of-your-application-instances


    package io.confluent.examples.streams;

import ...;

public class ResetDemo {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Kafka Streams configuration
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "my-streams-app");
    // ...and so on...

    // Define the processing topology
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    builder.stream("my-input-topic")
        .selectKey(...)
        .through("rekeyed-topic")
        .groupByKey()
        .count("global-count")
        .to("my-output-topic");

    KafkaStreams app = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), props);

    // Delete the application's local state.
    // Note: In real application you'd call `cleanUp()` only under
    // certain conditions.  See tip on `cleanUp()` below.
    app.cleanUp();

    app.start();

    // Note: In real applications you would register a shutdown hook
    // that would trigger the call to `app.close()` rather than
    // using the sleep-then-close example we show here.
    Thread.sleep(30 * 1000L);
    app.close();
  }

}
```

followed by the following example:

Tip: To avoid the corresponding recovery overhead, you should not call cleanUp() unconditionally and every time an application instance is restarted or resumed. For exammple, in a production application you could use command line arguments to enable or disable the cleanUp() call on an as-needed basis.

You can then perform run-reset-modify cycles as follows:

```
    # Run your application
  bin/kafka-run-class io.confluent.examples.streams.ResetDemo

# After stopping all application instances, reset the application
  bin/kafka-streams-application-reset --application-id my-streams-app \
                                      --input-topics my-input-topic \
                                      --intermediate-topics rekeyed-topic

# Now you can modify/recompile as needed and then re-run the application again.
# You can also experiment, for example, with different input data without
# modifying the application.
```

I do not understand it.

1. Does app.cleanUp () require app.start() to be executed ?
2. Why having a app.cleanUp () followed by an app.start(), in what circumstances would that be useful ?
3. Why not just having a flag that say if it is cleanUp then just run app.cleanUp(), and it is not run app.start();

I simply do not understand the last part of the example

run your app then apply the reset tool. but if the app look like in the example, then after the cleanUp, the app will run and we will have local data. So stopping will not help the rest-tool.

It is very confusing. Can someone who understand it explain please ?

Answer (score 1):

Running the application reset tool, ensures that your application’s state – as tracked globally in the application’s configured Kafka cluster – is reset. However, by design the reset tool does not modify or reset the local environment of your application instances, which includes the application’s local state directory. 
For a complete application reset you must also delete the application’s local state directory on any machines on which an application instance was run prior to restarting an application instance on the same machines. You can either use the API method KafkaStreams#cleanUp() in your application code or manually delete the corresponding local state directory  (`state.dir` configuration parameter).

`app.cleanup()` method deletes the local statestores. `app.startUp()` starts the KStream application.

> 1. Does app.cleanUp () require app.start() to be executed ?

`app.cleanup()` method deletes the local statestores. `app.startUp()` is required to start the KStream application. If you want to just cleanup the stores, you can call only `cleanUp()` only. But if you want to start the app, you need to call `startUp()` method too.

> 2. Why having a app.cleanUp () followed by an app.start(), in what circumstances would that be useful ?

When you want to reset the application to the earliest offset and run it from the beginning, you need to call `cleanUp()` method. If you want to resume the stopped application from the current state, don't call cleanUp() in your application code. 
It is not recommended to use default cleanup as a part of appplication unless needed. Also you can't delete the stores in a running application so always call `cleanUp()` before `startUp()` method.

> 3. Why not just having a flag that say if it is cleanUp then just run app.cleanUp(), and it is not run app.start();

Yes, you can do that based on your use case. Define a flag in configuration file, and add a conditional cleanup. Example :

```
if(cleanUpFlag){
   app.cleanUp();
}
app.start();
```

If you want to automate the entire process for global and local cleanup, you can write a script which takes a configuration file as input. You can update the flag value `flag=true` in that configuration file as true. Also make sure that the config variable is used in if condition.

```
if(properties.getProperty("cleanUp.flag") == true){
       app.cleanUp();
    }
```

Example :

```
# After stopping all application instances, reset the application
$ bin/kafka-streams-application-reset --application-id my-streams-app \
                                      --input-topics my-input-topic \
                                      --intermediate-topics rekeyed-topic \
                                       --bootstrap-servers brokerHost:9092 \
                                      --zookeeper zookeeperHost:2181


# Run your application
$ java –DApp.config.file=app.properties –jar KStreamDemo.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your last code does not correspond exactly to what i was looking for. What i meant was "if (cleanUpFlag) app.cleanUp() else app.start();"

Comment: My point being, the only way i can see the rest tool working is calling only cleanUp and exiting. hence "if (cleanUpFlag) app.cleanUp() else app.start();". Then once exiting, it makes sense to use the reset tool. in other words, call your app with the flag and then use the reset tool. But call the rest tool after an application that use code "if (cleanUpFlag) { app.cleanUp() } app.start();" does not make sense to me. Because the state store will not be empty even if i have the flag. the application will be started anyway. That's why i find the example extremely confusing or misleading

Comment: Unless i am still missing something ?

Comment: Updated the answer. It is simple to understand, if you want to automate the cleanup and start process, put together in your app code When you restart the app, it will automatically clean the state stores before starting. In that case, you don't have to run the reset tool locally. But it you run the instances in a cluster, you will consider using global reset, instead of doing on each machine. There you should use reset tool instead of calling cleanup in each instance.

Comment: I think your answer is great. Your last comment create confusion however. The reset tool is not just about local state store. It is about internal topics, it is about consumer groups and what not. This is well explained here https://www.confluent.io/blog/data-reprocessing-with-kafka-streams-resetting-a-streams-application/#details. They explicitly state that reseting your kafka application is a 2 step process. if you only clean up your local store, you change nothing but ensure that you will read the changelog of your delete localstore to rebuild it and resume where you were.

Comment: What i am looking to do is a process to reprocess my entire stream application on demand. Clean local store, reset global, and start again.

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks for pointing out. It is a 2-step process and reset tool wont cleanup the state. If you want it on demand, I recommend to use a script where you stop your app as #1, run reset tool as #2 , pass a flag config to true in kstream start command as #3 which will run the conditional cleanup in your kstream app. Updated the answer

Comment: "if (cleanUpFlag) app.cleanUp() else app.start();" or "if (cleanUpFlag) { app.cleanUp() } app.start();" The 2 line of code implies 2 different things. My issue is that the 2 second line seems wrong to me, it should be the first. Your last update avoid "app.start()" :) ! Should it be code 1 or code 2 ?

Comment: you need to have the app.startUp() to as entrypoint to start the application instance. Otherwise, your app will just cleanup but won't run anything.

Comment: I think i understand now your appraoch. I was thinking about it the other way around. So you do the global reset first then you run with the flag. I was thinking about doing a clean up first and then a global rest, and then running your application again.

Comment: Both approach are okay. At the end, you have to see which one is easy to manage.  :)